# How do I call a function from the jQuery $(document).ready?

Tags: jquery

I've been working with Angular for so long, I can't remember how do this basic task in jQuery. How to call a function from $(document).ready. This is my latest attempt:

```
app.alerts = app.alerts || {};

app.alerts.detailsChecklist = function () {
  var validate = function () {
     // do stuff
     // return true or false
  }
}();

$(document).ready(function () {
   if (app.alerts.detailsChecklist.validate())
      localStorage.setItem('valid', 'true');
   else
      localStorage.setItem('valid', 'false');
});
```

I get this error: app.alerts.detailsChecklist.validate is not a function.

Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: you are executing the detailsChecklist function immediately, which returns `null` which isn't a function.  Also mind that variables are bound to `window` if they aren't scoped (eg. a self executing function), which could cause issues when third party javascript is loaded and may use the same variables. I've seen it over and over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code snippet, you're only creating a function inside a function (`validate` inside `detailsChecklist`).

You haven't made `validate` an accessible property of the `detailsChecklist` object.

Since you're using an immediately invoked function expression to create your `detailsChecklist` object, this function needs to return an object with whatever properties are supposed to be accessible.

```js
const app = {}

app.alerts = app.alerts || {};

app.alerts.detailsChecklist = function() {
  const validate = function() {
    // do stuff
    // return true or false
    console.info('validate!!')
  }

  return {
    validate
  }
}();

$(document).ready(function() {
  if (app.alerts.detailsChecklist.validate())
    console.info('is valid')
  else
    console.info('is not valid')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I return that object in my example?

Comment: @Scott I updated my example. You return whatever `detailsChecklist` is supposed to be.

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot to mark your answer as correct. Thanks!